# Constant definitions not valid any more with PHP 5.4.x?

Tags: php, constants, notice

I'm trying to (in a parallel fashion, that's it, as we're still developing under PHP 5.2.x for our main applications) adapt our current applications to PHP 5.4.x (using Apache 2.4.2 with PHP 5.4.1 in our testing server) but I'm finding some warnings in our current applications when we run them in the testing server.

For example... we're using constant definition in our current applications with a function that detects the language and loads a language file containing the definitions like *idiomas/**lang**.php*, being ***lang*** a 2-digit language representation (es, us, de, and so on).

Inside each language file there's some definitions like this one:

```
define("IDIOMA_AF", "Afrikaans");
define("IDIOMA_AR", "العربية");
define("IDIOMA_BG", "български език");
```

So, when we want to output a given translated text, we do this:

```
<?php echo IDIOMA_AF; ?>
```

The message PHP 5.4.1 outputs when the application is thrown at it is the following:

```
Notice: Constant IDIOMA_AF already defined in D:\apache\htdocs\aplicacion\modulos\base\idiomas\es.php on line 34
```

Does anyone have the same problem? I would like to know a bit about your experiences, as it would be useful to know how to solve these problems. We're thinking on implementing a better system using gettext (which I think is more organized and easier to handle in the long run, but still...), although we would like to run our current applications for a while before upgrading them.

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump(IDIOMA_AF)` before to first lines you put here? And if you use [`get_defined_constants()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) do you see the `IDIOMA_AF` constant in there?

Comment: Sounds like the conditional loading of language files is not working as it has already loaded something that has defined that value (possibly another language file) or alternatively it is including the same language file more than once. May be worth running a [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Comment: Yeah, we were creating some duplicated entries as we have a base module which loads in the first place (on login) and secondary modules which loads afterwards (on demand), and they shared some definitions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you are trying to define the constant twice (which is not allowed).

You could try:

```
if (!defined('IDIOMA_AF')) define('IDIOMA_AF', 'Afrikaans');
```

Or trace, and fix, why you are defining a constant twice anyway.

The function `get_defined_constants()` is also a useful debugging tool for issues like these.

Or, just ignore those errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`

Comment: Good answer! It helped us to get rid of the notifications as we were actually duplicating some entries (our base module was already loading some definitions, which then were loaded by our application' sub-modules).

Definitely, gettext is the 'real' answer to our translation needs, but this did the trick :)